# How to search for nodes inside the boundaries of an area?

Tags: search

I am interested in searching for nodes inside the boundaries of an area .e.g. nodes inside "London" .How can I do that with Solr?
The existing modules only provide searning based on a radius you set.
Are there any other libraries that could help apart from drupal modules?
thanks